# PHP script works on mac but not on windows

Tags: curl, error-handling, php, parse-platform

I am utilizing parse.com and the PHP library for interacting with the framework is only working for me on a mac using MAMP, but on windows using XAMPP or WAMP, it fails for the same reason each time. Below is the function called each time a connection is made to parse. When ran on windows, $responseCode = 0 and $response is false. When I run it on my Mac, $responseCode = 200 and $response returns the json data it is suppose too. What is going on? Why would the different platforms be causing a failure?

```
public function request($args){
        $isFile = false;
        $c = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'parse.com-php-library/2.0');
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        if(substr($args['requestUrl'],0,5) == 'files'){
            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type: '.$args['contentType'],
                'X-Parse-Application-Id: '.$this->_appid,
                'X-Parse-Master-Key: '.$this->_masterkey
            ));
            $isFile = true;
        }
        else if(substr($args['requestUrl'],0,5) == 'users' && isset($args['sessionToken'])){
            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'X-Parse-Application-Id: '.$this->_appid,
                'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: '.$this->_restkey,
                'X-Parse-Session-Token: '.$args['sessionToken']
            ));
        }
        else{
            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'X-Parse-Application-Id: '.$this->_appid,
                'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: '.$this->_restkey,
                'X-Parse-Master-Key: '.$this->_masterkey
            )); 
        }
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $args['method']);
        $url = $this->_parseurl . $args['requestUrl'];

        if($args['method'] == 'PUT' || $args['method'] == 'POST'){
            if($isFile){
                $postData = $args['data'];
            }
            else{
                $postData = json_encode($args['data']);
            }

            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData );
        }

        if($args['requestUrl'] == 'login'){
            $urlParams = http_build_query($args['data'], '', '&');
            $url = $url.'?'.$urlParams;
        }
        if(array_key_exists('urlParams',$args)){
            $urlParams = http_build_query($args['urlParams'], '', '&');
            $url = $url.'?'.$urlParams;
        }

        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        $response = curl_exec($c);
        $responseCode = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        $expectedCode = '200';
        if($args['method'] == 'POST' && substr($args['requestUrl'],0,4) != 'push'){
            $expectedCode = '201';
        }

        if($expectedCode != $responseCode){
            //BELOW HELPS WITH DEBUGGING
                    //echo "VAR DUMP:";
                    //var_dump($response);      
        }

        return $this->checkResponse($response,$responseCode,$expectedCode);
    }

private function checkResponse($response,$responseCode,$expectedCode){
        //TODO: Need to also check for response for a correct result from parse.com
        if($responseCode != $expectedCode) {

            $error = json_decode($response);
            $this->throwError($error->error,$error->code);
        }
        else{
            //check for empty return
            if($response == '{}'){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return json_decode($response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
[23-Jan-2013 19:57:45 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\firecom\parse\parse.php on line 180

[23-Jan-2013 19:57:45 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\firecom\parse\parse.php on line 180

[23-Jan-2013 19:57:45 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ParseLibraryException: [0]: thrown in C:\wamp\www\firecom\parse\parse.php on line 169
```

Comment: where's line 180? you definitely don't have 180 lines in that sample

Comment: line 180 is this: $this->throwError($error->error,$error->code);

Comment: probably means that your $response is not valid json, json_decode returned a boolean false, and you blindly used that false as an object. Try `if ($error === false) { die(json_last_error()); }` or something to check for such things.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
$response = curl_exec($c);
```

With:

```
if( ! $response = curl_exec($c) ) {
    die(curl_error($c));
}
```

Or substitute whatever error-handling code you like.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: Ok so the error is SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate. What does that mean?

Comment: They might be using a self-signed cert, or the server you're running on doesn't have its root/intermediate certs up to date. If you don't care about this, then use `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);`

Comment: @JonErickson "This diesel worked fine in my tractor, but when I put it in my car the engine won't start!" You have no idea how much I despise that question. A) You might not have your root/intermediate certificates up to date. B) Some versions of cURL don't like wildcard certs. C) Every other reason.

Comment: @JonErickson beats me, I haven't used a Mac in decades. Try http://superuser.com/ or http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JonErickson woop, brainfart. Windows Update handles the root certs, the server you're connecting to should really be providing the intermediates. Otherwise you'd have to get them from the issuing CA. I'm not sure how cURL handles receiving intermediate certificates, but cURL complains so much about SSL I always throw in NOVERIFY. Put the `curl_setopt()` line in with the rest of them near the top of that block of code you posted, basically anywhere before `curl_exec()`.